How to Extract Transparent Images from a PDF Without Losing Transparency
I have a PDF that contains images with transparency. When I try to extract the images using tools like pdfimages, it outputs the image and the transparency layer as separate images, which is not ideal.
Is there a way to extract the images while preserving their transparency in a single file?
